# Not able To Invoke xpath-functions From XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0, apache-fop

I am trying out to invoke the xpath functions from xslt; below is a sample code block

```
<fo:block>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;  abs(7) = </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="abs(7)"/>
</fo:block>
```

I had added
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions"  in my DTD

```
abs
```

is for absolute value of a given number

I am getting below error:

```
SystemId Unknown; Line #116; Column #58; Could not find function: abs
SystemId Unknown; Line #116; Column #58; function token not found.
(Location of error unknown)java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.xpath.Expression.exprSetParent(org.apache.xpath.ExpressionNode)" because "expr" is null
[ERROR] FOP - Exception <org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.xml.transform.Transformer.setParameter(String, Object)" because "transformer" is null
```

Comment: Functions like `fn:abs` https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-abs where introduced in XPath 2.0; if you use an XSLT 1.0 processor like Apache Xalan you don't have support for XSLT 2.0 or XPath 2.0; in the Java world this can usually easily be fixed by putting a version of Saxon HE on the classpath as Saxon HE by now supports even XSLT 3.0 and XPath 3.1.

Comment: I am using xslt 2 xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"

Comment: You need to use software that supports XSLT 2 if you want to use XSLT 2. In the Java world the built-in Transformer in the Open or Oracle JDKs is usually an internalized version of Apache Xalan and Xalan doesn't support XSLT 2 at all. To use XSLT 2 or 3 in the Java world, the easiest solution is to put a recent version of Saxon HE on the classpath.

Comment: https://github.com/Saxonica/Saxon-HE/blob/main/12/Java/SaxonHE12-1J.zip is the correct link ?

Comment: Yes, or of course, getting it from Maven.